# How to create an aggregation over unique count in Kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, visualization, vega

I have an index in ElasticSeach with data for last 6h like:

```
[
        {
        "user": "001",
        "id": "001001",
        "timeOK": "true",
        "timestamp": "1649246222885"
      },
        {
        "user": "002",
        "id": "002002",
        "timeOK": "true",
        "timestamp": "1649246222887"
      },
        {
        "user": "003",
        "id": "003003",
        "timeOK": "true",
        "timestamp": "1649246222888"
      },
        {
        "user": "001",
        "id": "001001",
        "timeOK": "false",
        "timestamp": "1649246222899"
      },
                {
        "user": "001",
        "id": "001001",
        "timeOK": "false",
        "timestamp": "1649246224899"
      },
                {
        "user": "004",
        "id": "002002",
        "timeOK": "true",
        "timestamp": "1649246223299"
      },
     ]
```

Every time there is an interaction of the user I am logging a new record. I am trying to find a way how to create a visualization which would present an average of unique counts per id in last 6h (or any time interval).
So for example above in last 6h there is:

> ```
> "id": "001001" unique count 3
> "id": "002002" unique count 2
> "id": "003003" unique count 1
> ```

So the average would be 2. Is it possible to create a visualization for this? Or a way how I can get and present that data?

Comment: How many ids do you have?

Comment: you can perform aggregate transform on your dataset, display it in a bar chart visualization and then use a rule to signify the average value. [visualtsation_example](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykSArJQBWENgDsQAGhAATONABONHJnaT0AQQAETJBBpRdSRdtgnM2uAA8kCHABs4U7QHc6MbcSQOGcbQ5ITHAOENoQMGyu4toMOBLaCGwMEP6RpIqU0iDusvRoACwADEUy8DRkWGgATCUyOEiysjTiZGgCMrJImCioANqg4nZwaCA9TE7Z3r4KaAMgKXCKoyUAjNk0sitFq2vZaghwAPIA0qOYin77NIcQPfajqwBsBQCc1QVP1d8AHD8CIAAvlJQItlugStUNlsIUVanDrodTudLiMZAcFPccI8Xu9Pt9qn8AOxAkELVLgkAlADM0O21JpiOOZ3QFy